# Access an html node in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, tags

I have following html code.

```
<div id="polaroid">
    <figure>
        <img src="assets/polaroid01.jpg" width="200" height="200" alt="Red mushroom" />
        <figcaption>Pretty red mushroom</figcaption>
    </figure>
    <figure>
        <img src="assets/polaroid02.jpg" width="200" height="200" alt="Rainbow near Keswick" />
        <figcaption>Rainbow near Keswick</figcaption>
   </figure>
   <figure>
        <img src="assets/polaroid03.jpg" width="200" height="200" alt="An old tree" />
        <figcaption>Nice old tree</figcaption>
   </figure>
</div><!--end polaroid-->
```

In this i want to store all the image tags in an array. I know, I can access the figure tags like this.

```
var images= document.getElementById('gall').getElementsByTagName('figure');
```

But i don't know how to access the image tag.
I tried this.

```
document.getElementById('gall').getElementsByTagName('figure').getElementsByTagName('img');
```

But this doesn't work.

Comment: it doesn't work because `getElementsByTagName` returns a node list, not a single node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case it's more convenient to use [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll):

```
var images = document.querySelectorAll('#gall figure img');
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean like this:

```
var images= document.getElementById('gall').getElementsByTagName('figure');
images.getElementsByTagName("img");
```

Comment: hmm. What errors are you getting in the console when you try the above Sheldon?

Answer (score 0):

This is possible if you use JQuery. Simply Do This.

1. Include Jquery Library (any version).
2. select image : $("#polaroid img").(any action);

Example:

put this above your code:

```html
<script src="../js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    
$(document).ready(function() { 

$("#polaroid img").css("border", "1px solid #000000");

});

</script>
```

---